# how to format with double quotes using f-format in python?

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

I want to enclose each element of a list with double quotes instead of single?

With f-string I'm not able to get double quotes and when I try solutions from the internet it's applying double quotes to the elements inside the `e` list.

```
res.append(f'{name}[{", ".join(e)}]')
```

This gives the output as

```
['Rishi[EC1]', 'Divya[]']
```

but I want it as

```
["Rishi[EC1]", "Divya[]"]
```

The whole code:

```
s=list(input().split(" "))
res=[]
EC1=["CC1","CC2"]
EC2=["CC1","CC2"]
EC3=["CC1","CC3"]
EC4=["CC1","CC2","CC3"]
EC5=["CC2","CC5"]
EC6=["CC4","CC5"]
for i in s:
    e=[]
    stu=i.split("/")
    name=stu[0]
    courses=stu[1:-1]
    gpa=stu[-1]
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC1)) and float(gpa)>=7.00:
        e.append("EC1")
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC2)) and float(gpa)>=8.00:
        e.append("EC2")
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC3)) and float(gpa)>=0.00:
        e.append("EC3")
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC4)) and float(gpa)>=9.00:
        e.append("EC4")
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC5)) and float(gpa)>=6.00:
        e.append("EC5")
    if (all(x in courses for x in EC6)) and float(gpa)>=0.00:
        e.append("EC6")

    if not e:
        res.append(f'{name}[{", ".join(e)}]')
    else:
        res.append(f"{name}[{', '.join(e)}]")
print(res)
```

input and output required:

```
Rishi/CC1/CC2/7.59 Divya/CC3/CC5/CC2/5.2
["Rishi['EC1']", 'Divya[]']

Ria/CC1/CC2/CC3/9.59 Divya/CC3/CC5/CC4/8.2 Ayush/CC3/CC4/CC5/6.5
["Ria['EC1', 'EC2', 'EC3', 'EC4']", "Divya['EC6']", "Ayush['EC6']"]
```

basically i need double quotes around elements in res which have non empty e lists, and if the e list for some elemnt is empty its single quotes

Comment: Swap `'` and `"` in your code. But really, it's not clear what exactly the problem is because we can't see the input. And it's not clear whether you want a list containing strings or a string representation of a list, and whether the strings should *contain* double quotes or you just want them to be *displayed* with double quotes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it dosent work i used ```res.append(f"{name}[{', '.join(e)}]")``` still i get single quotes